# Derivative respect to integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

Did anybody knows how to take this derivative $\frac{d\int_{a}^{b}z\sqrt{x}df(z)}{dx}$?

Is it correct answer $\frac{d\int_{a}^{b}z\sqrt{x}df(z)}{dx}=\int_{a}^{b}z\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}df(z)$?

P.S. x and z are independend variables

Will be very greatful for help!

Comment: I do not understand the d constant in $df(z)$, don't you mean $\frac{d}{dx}f(z)$

Comment: Yes, $d$ means differentiation, but differentiation respect to the whole integral

Comment: I am sorry, but I am very unaware of the notation $df(z)$. How would one interpret it?

Comment: Square root of $x $ can come out of integral :-)

Comment: Math-fun, really. I thought it like a sum (integral) of derivatives, but taking out of integral really makes differentiation simple as a day) thank you!

Comment: @Math-fun You should answer the question since you understand it best.

Comment: Since the integral is with respect to $z $ and x has nothing to do with z, the integral "thinks" that x is a constant and as such it goes out of integral.

Comment: @Math-fun I mistakended the integral to be with respect to $x$. So Bogdan is right.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches how to think about this problem. The first one is to think it as an integral of derivatives. It is good for a problems like $\frac{\partial\int_{a}^{b}f(x,z)dg(z)}{\partial x}=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial f(x,z)}{\partial x}dg(z)$. The other approach is good for cases $\frac{\partial \int_{a}^{b}f(x)k(z)dg(z)}{\partial x}=(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x})*\int_{a}^{b}k(z)dg(z)$ so we just think about an integral as about a constant.

Finally, the problem in the question (**idea of Math-fun**) mets the second approach very well so $\frac{\partial\int_{a}^{b}z\sqrt{x}df(z)}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\int_{a}^{b}zdf(z)$.